# GitHub Pages not sending pre-rendered content built with Angular universal

Tags: angular, github-pages, angular-universal

I am trying to deploy a pre-rendered web-application with GitHub Pages.
What I have done is to pre-render everything locally and commit them to the a `hosted-demo` branch.

Therefore my docs folder looks like this:

```
docs/
docs/fast-svg/index.html
docs/fast-svg/?ls=distributed&list=1/index.html
docs/index.html
... ETC ...
```

If I inspect the document located at `docs/fast-svg/?ls=distributed&list=1/index.html` I can see it is correctly pre-rendered.

However if I inspect the file received from navigating to `https://push-based.github.io/ngx-fast-svg/fast-svg?ls=distributed&list=1`, I can see it is the file located at `docs/fast-svg/index.html`.

I was originally trying to have the page without the `/`
Like this `docs/fast-svg/?ls=distributed&list=1/index.html` -> docs/fast-svg`/`?ls=distributed&list=1/index.html
Instead of `docs/fast-svg?ls=distributed&list=1/index.html` -> docs/fast-svg ?ls=distributed&list=1/index.html

However, GitHub Pages was redirecting using a `301`

Redirected to from:
`https://push-based.github.io/ngx-fast-svg/fast-svg?ls=distributed&list=1`
To:
`https://push-based.github.io/ngx-fast-svg/fast-svg/?ls=distributed&list=1`

Here is a link to a PR describing the redirection issue:
[Demo not serving pre-rendered docs](https://github.com/push-based/ngx-fast-svg/issues/44)

Comment: Are you sure about angular universal will work on deploying to github pages?

Comment: Well it is not an SSR but SSG app because I am pre-rendering everything. 
So yes it should work right?

Comment: If you are doing SSG then see `scully` https://scully.io/ is doing the same thing for you.

Comment: Cool, will defiantly try out `Scully` but the problem is not the pre-rendering, it's that the pre-rendered page is not being fetched.